# Getting records between two dates changing at 04:00AM instead of 00:00

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the orders records between today date at 11 am until tomorrow date until 4 am.

I have tried the below code and start_date results `2017-04-20 11:00:00.000` and end date `2017-04-21 04:00:00.000`

but the problem is when the clock reach 12 am  at (Midnight) the  start_date results `2017-04-21 11:00:00.000` and end date `2017-04-22 04:00:00.000` start date and end date should have the same above values.

How can I solve this issue

**Query**

```
DECLARE @start_date datetime = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(9), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 112) + '11:00');
DECLARE @end_date datetime = DATEADD(HOUR, 17, @start_date)
SELECT * from [dbo].[Orders] where [OrderDate] between  @start_date and @end_date
```

Comment: So, when do you want the date to change? at 4 am?

Comment: correct after 4 am

Comment: I dont understand the problem here. Isnt that your desired value?

Comment: after 4 am date will change so start_date will be 2017-04-21 11:00:00.000 and end 2017-04-22 04:00:00.000 etc..

Comment: Instead of using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` directly subtract four hours, so the first four hours count for the previous day and you are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if your current date is before 4AM and substract a day in this case.

```
DECLARE @from datetime 
set @from = getdate();
if (DATEPART(HOUR, @from) < 4) set @from = dateadd(day, -1, @from);

DECLARE @start_date datetime = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(9), @from, 112) + '11:00');
DECLARE @end_date datetime =     

SELECT * from [dbo].[Orders] where [OrderDate] between  @start_date and @end_date
```

Test :

```
DECLARE @from datetime 
--set @from = getdate();
set @from = '2017-04-21 02:00'  -- We test a value instead of using the current datetime
if (DATEPART(HOUR, @from) < 4) set @from = dateadd(day, -1, @from);

DECLARE @start_date datetime = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(9), @from, 112) + '11:00');
DECLARE @end_date datetime = DATEADD(HOUR, 17, @start_date)

SELECT @start_date, @end_date   -- Test result

SELECT * from [dbo].[Orders] where [OrderDate] between  @start_date and @end_date
```

Testing it with 2017-04-21 02:00, it returns : 2017-04-20 11:00 and 2017-04-21 04:00

Comment: The query results orders between 2017-04-19 and 2017-04-20 it should not show that

Comment: start date result 2017-04-19 11:00:00.000 and end date 2017-04-20 04:00:00.000 it should be 2017-04-20 11:00:00.000 and 2017-04-21 4:00:00.000

Comment: From what date value are you trying ?. Replace the getdate() by '2017-04-21 02:00', it will return 2017-04-20 11:00 and 2017-04-21 04:00. Isn't this what you are looking for ?.

Comment: i don't have fixed values

Comment: it will change day by day

Comment: Yes, it's just for test, we set a value to test if it returns the result that you desire. But obviously on the end you will leave it with a getdate() instead of those testing values.

Comment: I have updated the answer, adding a test there. If this is not the result that you look for that datetime, please tell what should it be.